# How can I make my Merge Sort Code In C more secure, effective and efficient

Tags: algorithm, c, sorting, mergesort

I have been implementing the `merge-sort` algorithm for sorting the data for a long time, each time I use the following source code for implementation.
By secure, I mean, taking care of memory management, loopholes etc.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>
void mergesort(int*,int,int);
void mergeSequence(int*,int,int,int); //Merge the two arrays
void displaySequence(int*);
int n;
int main()
{
    int t,test;
    int*num=NULL;
    int i;
    printf("Enter the number of test cases\n", test);
    scanf("%d", &test);
    assert(test>0);
    for(t=0;t<test;t++)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the sequence\n", n);
        scanf("%d", &n);
        assert(n>0);
        num=calloc(sizeof(int),n);
        assert(num);
        printf("Enter the sequence\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d", (num+i));
        printf("Sequence before sorting\n");
        displaySequence(num);
        mergeSort(num,0,(n-1));
        printf("Sequence after sorting\n");
        display(num);
        free(num);
    }
    return 0;
}
void displaySequence(int*num)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ", num[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void mergeSort(int*num,int start,int end)
{
    int mid;
    mid=start+((end-start)/2);
    printf("Mid->%d\n", mid);
    if(start<end)
    {
        mergeSort(num,start,mid);
        mergeSort(num,(mid+1),end);
        mergeSequence(num,start,mid,end);
    }

}
void mergeSequence(int*num,int start,int mid,int end)
{
    int n1,n2;
    int i,j,k;
    n1=(mid-start)+1;
    n2=(end-mid);
    printf("N1->%d\nN2->%d\n", n1,n2);
    int left[n1];
    int right[n2];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        left[i]=num[start+i];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        printf("%d ", left[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        right[j]=num[(mid+1)+j];
    for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
        printf("%d ", right[j]);
    printf("\n");
    //Now I have two arrays, and I can now merge them
    k=start;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while((k<=end))
    {
        if(i==n1)
        {
            num[k]=right[j];
            j++;
        }
        else if(j==n2)
        {
            num[k]=left[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if(left[i]<=right[j])
        {
            num[k]=right[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
        else
        {
            num[k]=left[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        k++;
    }
    displaySequence(num);
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Consider posting a follow-up question linking back to this one instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> make the code more compact and secure

**Separate sort code from test code**

To well address security issues, OP needs to present a clear distinction between what is the sort code and what is not.  Put all *sort* code in a separate .c file.

**int vs. size_t**

C employs `size_t` as the type that is neither to narrow nor too wide for array indexing and sizing.

Although `int` is commonly sufficient, to make more *secure* and work with large data, use `size_t`.

Aside from changing `int` --> `size_t` and `"%d"` --> `"%zu"`, a singular challenge is to remember `size_t` is some *unsigned* type and code needs to consider that.  `(size_t)x < 0` is never true.

**Beware large VLAs**

Security risk: `int left[n1];` is subject to *stack overflow*.  Consider `*alloc()` instead.  Insufficient memory can be detected that way.

**Avoid exposing helper functions**

`mergeSequence()` is not meant to be used outside of `mergesort()`.  To prevent other code from using this functions, make it `static`.  Further, put it and `mergesort()` in their own .c file.

This increases security as `mergeSequence()`  then not need to handle all sorts of arguments, just the ones `mergesort()` generates.

**All warnings enabled?**

Save time, enable all warnings.

I'd expect `mergeSort(num,0,(n-1));` (upper case S) to warn about function usage before declaration.

`void mergesort(int*,int,int);` (lower case S) is declared but not used.

**Avoid generic names when a specific type is required**

`mergeSort()` sorts `int`.  With a name like `mergeSort`, I expected something like `qsort()` with its size-of-element parameter and compare function.

Of re-architect your merge sort code to take a generic object type.

```
void SS_mergeSort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, 
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));`
```

**Compact by eliminating print out**

It is unexpected that a sort routine would do any printing.  Remove `printf()` and `displaySequence()` from `merge...()` functions.

**Compact left,right code**

`int left[n1]; int right[n2];` can be `int left_right[n1+n2];` and then the copying facilitated with the fast lib function `memcpy()`.

```
memcpy(left_right, num, sizeof left_right);
int *left = left_right;
int *right = left_right + n1;
...
```

Comment: Are there platforms where overflowing program stack is a *security* bug?  On most platforms, it's trapped and merely results in program termination.

Comment: @TobySpeight Any form of exception is a crack in security.  Most platforms in 2018 are  embedded processors (billions per year) and which may terminate the program - only to restart it.

Comment: Stack overflow usually results in a signal, rather than an exception, but that aside, if terminating the program is a *security* risk, then that speaks more to whatever's running it that the program itself.  I still agree that it's something worth avoiding, of course, but disagree on the motivation.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the question uses the term "security" to refer to what I'd call *robustness* - i.e. functional correctness in the face of difficult (or even hostile) input, rather than what I'd call *security* - resistant to attempts to perform unauthorised actions.

Comment: @TobySpeight A crack in "functional correctness in the face of difficult (or even hostile) input" is often a first step to defeating "resistant to attempts to perform unauthorised actions".

Answer (score 5):

## Errors

1. You use `printf()` to print the number of testcases etc. and give it more arguments than specified in the format string (clang: `-Wformat-extra-args`).
2. You have conflicting types for `mergeSort()` as you declare `mergesort()` (lower-case `s`!) at the top and the use of `mergeSort()` in `main()` implicitly declares `int mergeSort()` which differs from `void mergeSort(int *, int, int)`.
3. The function `display()` does not exist; it should be called `displaySequence()`.
4. You use assertions to check user input, that's wrong. Assertions will be removed from code when `NDEBUG` is declared and are only used to state and verify assumptions that you already have in the code.  Correct use of the assert would be:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &test);
   if (test <= 0) {
       return 1;
   }
   /* We can now assume that test > 0 */
   assert (test > 0);
   ```

   Assertions are used to safeguard against eg. future changes where you might forgot that the following code assumes `test > 0`.

## Good practice

1. Declare your module-local functions and variables `static`.
2. Declare functions taking no arguments as `f(void);`.  E.g. `f();` specifies that this function "has no parameters", where "parameter" is a restriction on what kind of arguments this function can take.  "No parameters" means "no restriction", that is the following is legal as long as the implementation of `f()` actually uses the argument:

   ```
   f();
   g() {
      f(42); // legal
   }
   ```

   If you instead write `f(void);` you provide a function prototype with the parameter "no arguments", ie. this is illegal:

   ```
   f(void);
   g() {
      f(42); // illegal
   }
   ```
3. Also the C99 feature of mixing declarations and code is useful as it compacts the code more and doesn't make you think "what was that variable used for again?":

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       /* ... */
       for (/* declaration -> */ int t = 0; t < test; t++) {
           /* ... */
       }
   }
   ```
4. *Don't* initialize variables when they don't have a reasonable value yet, eg. `num`. This only stops the compiler from warning you about "use of uninitialized value" but doesn't help against unwanted behavior.  But if you use the previous point, you can even initialize the variable directly on declaration
5. Check the return value of library functions such as `scanf()`:

   ```
   if (scanf("%d", &test) != 1) {
       return 1;
   }
   ```
6. Don't use global variables such as `n`.
7. Always pass the length of the buffer when passing it around, ie.:

   ```
   void displaySequence(size_t len, int *num);
   /* void displaySequence(size_t len, int num[len]); <- Alternative syntax */
   ```
8. Use `size_t` for amounts of memory etc.
9. You can concatenate C-string-literals if you just write them after another, making this more readable:

   ```
   printf("N1->%zu\n"
          "N2->%zu\n", n1, n2);
   ```
10. Use `const` where possible.
11. When allocating, use this:

    ```
    int *const num = calloc(sizeof (*num), n);
    ```

    instead of:

    ```
    int *const num = calloc(sizeof (int), n);
    ```

    As it allows you to change the type and the code will not (possibly silently) fail.
12. Use `perror` to get localized and standardized error messages (`calloc()` setting `errno` is however a POSIX C extension and might not be available on some platforms, cf. comments):

    ```
    int *const num = calloc(sizeof (*num), n);
    if (!num) {
        perror("calloc");
        return 1;
    }
    ```
13. Don't use VLAs; they are dangerous (and IIRC even deprecated). They basically allow an attacker to overflow your stack here, with pretty much no safeguards possible for you.
14. Don't mix pointer-arithmetic and array-notation:

    ```
    scanf("%d", &num[i]); /* was: scanf("%d", num+i); */
    ```

## Style

1. Use empty lines to structure your code. Eg. I have:

   ```
   printf("Enter the sequence\n");
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (scanf("%d", num+i) != 1) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
           return 1;
       }
   }

   printf("Sequence before sorting\n");
   displaySequence(num, n);

   mergeSort(num, 0, n-1);

   printf("Sequence after sorting\n");
   displaySequence(num, n);

   free(num);
   ```
2. In a similar vein, use horizontal space more. I'm more or less following the Kernel Normal Form (KNF), with spaces after commas, around operators, after keywords, before the pointer indicator, etc.  If you do that, you don't need weird things parenthesis `mergeSort(num,0,(n+1))` anymore as visual aid.  It's far easier on the eye.
3. Use braces for `if-else`: it's such a common bug to forget them when expanding the if-statement.  Or at least write them in one line otherwise.

## Security

This is tricky. In general: Don't trust user input, at all. Everything passed into `scanf()` is user-controlled.  Currently the user can overflow your stack, try to allocate as much memory as possible (and since you don't check for the success of `malloc()`, possibly write memory). As the user also controls the actual sequence, in theory they could even try to write arbitrary stuff into memory.

Comment: I recommend the use of `perror()`, but your use here isn't correct: `calloc()` is not specified to set `errno` when it fails.  You need to either set `errno` to `ENOMEM` before calling `perror()`, output `strerror(ENOMEM)`, or print a fixed message.  `ENOMEM` is specified by POSIX, but isn't part of standard C, so the last option is the portable choice (though the POSIX-specified options may be internationalised, so could be a better option when available).

Comment: Great answer. Minor quibble: I wouldn’t put parentheses around the argument to `sizeof` unless it’s required (complex expression, or type name).

Comment: @TobySpeight Ah, yeah, I always check against POSIX, since it specifies `calloc` shall set `ENOMEM` on fail (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), but yes, that is a CX (I'll amend that).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks! I'm more or less following the KNF there which also specifies `return (1)` (which I deviate from), or more specifically: Parenthesis around all keyword arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## Always check the result of `scanf()`

This code optimistically assumes that numeric inputs are successfully parsed.  We need to check that the result of `scanf()` (the number of conversions successfully parsed and assigned) matches our expectations before using any of the values.

## Don't use `assert()` for testing input validity

When reading user input, if we wish to check that we have more than 0 tests and more than 0 entries in each test, then `assert()` is the wrong tool.  Remember that it can be disabled by defining `NDEBUG`, and it commonly is, for optimized builds.

Consider also using unsigned types for values that can't be negative.

## Always check the result of memory allocation

Allocation functions such as `calloc()` can always fail.  Again, `assert()` is not a robust means to check these.

## Unexpected output in the bagging area

It looks like these statements were accidentally left in after a debugging session, and should be removed:

> ```
> printf("Mid->%d\n", mid);
> ```

> ```
> printf("N1->%d\nN2->%d\n", n1,n2);
> ```

## No need to compute mid-point at end of recursion

Here, we only need `mid` if `start<end`:

> ```
> void mergeSort(int*num,int start,int end)
> {
>     int mid;
>     mid=start+((end-start)/2);
>     if(start<end)
>     {
>         mergeSort(num,start,mid);
>         mergeSort(num,(mid+1),end);
>         mergeSequence(num,start,mid,end);
>     }
> }
> ```

We can re-write it as

```
void mergeSort(int *num, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end) {
        const int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
        mergeSort(num, start, mid);
        mergeSort(num, mid+1, end);
        mergeSequence(num, start, mid, end);
    }
    /* else, start==end, and no work to do */
}
```

Comment: Concerning "Don't use assert() for testing input validity".  How do you use `assert()`?

Comment: @chux Assertions are for enforcing facts that _must_ be true according to the program logic. They are not meant for validating constraints on user input that you _hope_ to be true.

Comment: Still wondering of an example of how you use `assert()`.

Comment: You don't use `assert()` at all for tests on user input or other external conditions; you use a definite test that won't be compiled out.  Use `assert()` only to document things that cannot be false unless there's a program bug.

Comment: Trivial example: `if (a < 100) return;  double b = sqrt(a); assert (b >= 10);`  Obviously, it takes more complex code for the assertion to be useful.

Comment: A happy coincidence - a few days later I used `assert()` in [this answer](/a/206737/) (near the end of the final code block) - I've checked than `num` is in range to be found in the list; the assert documents my claim that an entry must be found.

Answer (score 4):

Properly document your code:
Is `void mergeSequence(int *values, int start, int mid, int end)`/`void mergeSort(int *values, int start, int end)` to merge/sort in ascending or descending order?
Is `int end` inclusive or exclusive?
(Considering some `mid` will be used to specify the end of some *left* as well as the start of some *right*, I think it **much** simpler to use the [inclusive, exclusive) convention.)

(One thing about declaring variables in the initialisation part of a for loop that [larkey](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234230/93149) did not mention is that the scope of each such variable is restricted to that statement.)

Readable, short source code is easier to grasp.
Procedural abstraction can reduce the amount of code.

You have `void displaySequence(int const *num)`, didn't use it in `void mergeSequence(int*, int,int, int)`. That may be because you chose to use a global variable `n` to communicate the amount of numbers to display - a static one would hardly have been better.
Note how in `main()` you print different labels to know what the value-sequences are about: that should probably be a parameter to `displaySequence()` as well as the number of values to print.

The `while`-loop is funny for more than one thing, starting with not being a `for`-loop:
You switch from `j++;` to `j=j+1;` (same for `i`).
Even if boiled down to

```
for (int k=start, i=0, j=0; k<=end ; k++)
    if (i==n1) {
        num[k]=right[j++];
    } else if(j==n2) {
        num[k]=left[i++];
    } else if(left[i]<=right[j]) {
        num[k]=right[j++];
    } else {
        num[k]=left[i++];
    }
```

, I can't make up my mind whether I'd rather
- relegate *only one part left* from this loop (→ bulk copy)
- use a *conditional expression* so as not to repeat `num[k]`